# permission shown to user is not same as dfined

Tags: php, facebook

in permission section of my app i have this Extended Permissions

```
manage_pages publish_stream status_update photo_upload video_upload create_note share_item publish_checkins
```

and when click on "Preview 
Configure your permissions" the dialog box and permission on it is right but when i want login from my app the request in app is only basic user info and this text show in below "This app may post on your behalf, including status updates, photos and more."

but i want manage page permission and don't have it

Answer (score -1):

the problem was i must set the all needed scopes in the first request for facebook

scopes must be comma separated